How to prevent JUnit test method from opening outbound Sockets?
I'm trying to ensure that my JUnit test method doesn't open any outbound Socket, mostly in order to be sure that it's a unit test, not an integration one. If it tries to open a socket, an exception should be raised. How can I do this (maybe with the help of an existing library)?

You could probably mock the socket and stub it so that the connection code does nothing or provide your own custom logic for the mock to perform

Did you try using tools like Byte Buddy or JMockit to intercept and mock the behavior of the Socket class, maybe one of these could be an option for you?

I understand that your intent is ensuring no underlying code does funny business. I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but you can achieve the same with ArchUnit. We do this. Just add annotations like @MyUnitTest and add a corresponding rule in ArchUnit that will ensure no dependency uses any method from Socket and friends. Works great

You could probably do this with a custom security policy, but that would be a real pain (and the security manager is deprecated for removal, so it won't work in the future).

@oligofren The code base would have dependencies on java.net.Socket but the unit tests should be written such a way that there would not be any call to java.net.Socket. Thank you for sharing ArchUnit but I don't think it is a solution to this problem.

@OSGIJava But if you do not want your tests to have dependencies on java.net.Socket you can create an archunit rule to throw when it encounters tests that do just that. noTestClasses().should().dependOnClassesThat()     .haveFullyQualifiedName(java.net.Socket). Just define noTestClasses() and you are good. How does this not answer the question?

@oligofren If I am testing a code that does open a socket then this code would have a dependency on java.net.Socket. I still want to write tests for this code.
I can write two tests, one that would open a socket and one that would not. Are you saying that with your ArchUnit rule, one test would execute and the other would fail?
Keep in mind that while the code can have a dependency on java.net.Socket, I can write a test such a way that it would not open a socket. I do want such test to execute. But when a socket is opened by an accident, I want the test to fail fast.

Yes, in a way, but I think you misunderstand what ArchUnit is. ArchUnit tests are separate from the other unit tests. They do not apply to a specific test. They enforce rules upon your architecture, which could (and should) include the tests. So if you write a archunit test like I mentioned above, the archunit test will fail and point to the test that fails your rules. The test creating the socket itself will run (and hopefully pass), but the tests will not, as you have specified that no test should have an explicit dependency on the Socket class. You can also be more specific.
